# how to differentiate list data in while loop php

Tags: php

If you can see this image there are main 4 pages. 1. issues.html  2. review issue.php  3.Another page.html 4. anotherpage.html

User inputs the query it goes to DB then I am fetching it on review issue page from DB using mysqli_fetch_array() and in the while loop, i am calling every row data present in DB. Review issue page shows all the issue list present in DB. But I want to send issue 1 data on some page called another page and issue 2 data on another page 2. For that what needs to be done. I ahve used local storage to function these checkboxes. You can see them in image. 
[image]
This is the code for Review-issue.php

```
                <?php
                 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH))   
                 {
                     ?>

                <div class="c-body">
                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert"> This issue has been reported by <?php echo $row['your_name']; ?> from <?php echo $row['store_name']; ?>
                    <p> <?php echo $row['issue_title']; ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $row['file'] ?></p>

                    <p><a href="uploads/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" target="_blank">View File </a></p>
                        <a class="c-font-slim" href="#">read this important alert message</a>.
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="c-content-panel">

                <div class="c-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body"> 
                                       <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Action</label>
                                     <form action="track.php" method="post">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="progressbar_chkbox"  type="checkbox" id="pending" data-progress="33" value="pending">Pending </label>

                                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                           <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" class="progressbar_chkbox" id="read" type="checkbox" data-progress="66" value="option2" value="read"> Read</label>

                                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                             <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" class="progressbar_chkbox" id="completed" type="checkbox" data-progress="100" value="option3" name="completed"> Completed </label>


                                              </div>
                                       </form>



                                </div>
                                 </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

                     <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Add the primary key of the issue, from the database, either to the form (for post submits) or to the link (as a GET parameter). Then use the primary key to query the data again on the new page

Comment: you can use $session there

Comment: I have used local storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a column in your database to identify which type of issue each record is, then add a conditional that will divide your results set into the two issue types. Then you can include the appropriate form for the issue type.

```
<?php 
if ($row["issue_type"] == 1) {
  include "issue1.php";    
} elseif ($row["issue_type"] == 2) {
  include "issue2.php";
} else {
  include "default.php";
}
?>
```

Comment: I got it mam. This is not working as per my expectations. what do i do?

Comment: This code presumes 2 things: 1) that there is a column in your database "issue_type" and 2) that you have two additional files named issue1.php and issue2.php each containing the form code specific to the issue type.   What exactly is happening? Please post details or errors you are receiving.